# how to make cross browser css ellipsis?

Tags: html, css, firefox

I used this

```
p.test {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;}
```

but it's not working on Firefox. And I didn't check on other browsers.

But I need cross browser compatibleway

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4927257/text-overflowellipsis-in-firefox-4

Comment: @thirtydot - Are all other browser supporting `text-overflow: ellipsis` except firefox

Comment: This is actually implemented in all major browsers except Firefox (which will receive this in version 6, due this year). (http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201105/clipping_text_with_css3_text-overflow/)

Comment: Yes - http://caniuse.com/#search=text-overflow

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Firefox doesn't support it.

There's a work-around for Firefox 3.x, but that also doesn't work in FF4.

I'm told that they plan to add support in FF6.

As of this moment, there is no CSS solution that works correctly for Firefox. There are some attempts that have managed to get something close, but nothing that's actually right.

For more, see also this question: [text-overflow:ellipsis in Firefox 4? (and FF5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4927257/text-overflowellipsis-in-firefox-4)

My current solution is to give up on having an ellipsis, and do something else instead. I'm using a fade-out effect on the right-hand side of the text element to give a similar visual cue to the user as an ellipsis, and it can even be combined with an ellipsis so we can support all browsers to show some kind of effect to show a text run-on without having to resort to any browser hacks.

**UPDATE** as per Ilee's answer:

> Since Firefox version 7 `text-overflow: ellipsis` is supported. Thus, it is cross browsers for major browsers like start from FF7, IE7 and Chrome.

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802175/truncating-long-strings-with-css-feasible-yet

Answer (score 7):

This post is outdated. Since Firefox version 7, it supports text-overflow: ellipsis. Thus, it is cross browsers for major browsers like start from ff7, IE7 and chrome.

Comment: I wouldn't say outdated.  I'm seeing this problem in Iceweasel 11.