# Is it possible to show dots '...' instead of letting text continue after the end of div?

Tags: html, css, layout, text, overflow

This is the example:

```
<style>
    div {
        background-color: skyblue;
        height: 100px;
    }

    .posttext {
        word-wrap: break-word;
        -ms-hyphenate-limit-lines: 10;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
    }
</style>
<div>
    <p class="posttext">---------0---------1---------2---------3---------4---------5---------6---------7---------8---------9---------0---------1---------2---------3---------4---------5---------6---------7---------8---------9---------0---------1---------2---------3---------4---------5---------6---------7---------8---------9---------0---------1---------2---------3---------4---------5---------6---------7---------8---------9---------0---------1---------2---------3---------4---------5---------6---------7---------8---------9---------0---------1---------2---------3---------4---------5---------6---------7---------8---------9---------0---------1---------2---------3---------4---------5---------6---------7---------8---------9---------0---------1---------2---------3---------4---------5---------6---------7---------8--------</p>
</div>
```

When you decrease the width of your browser enough the text will continue to show under the blue colored `div`. I found a way to stop it using  `'text-overflow: ellipsis'` but it stops at the first line.
Is it possible to make it continue until it reaches the height of the `div` and then show three dots at the end rather than continuing under it?

Comment: Did you try this one out? https://stackoverflow.com/a/3695438/3377857

Comment: In order for text overflow to work, the element it is applied to must have a set width/height so it can detect overflow. Also, the element's overflow property should be set to hidden.

Comment: @KlemensMorbe it works, but it doesn't show 3 dots at the end. Thank you though, I'll use this as a temporary solution until I find a way to add 3 dots at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below properties are useful when you want to show ellipsis at the end of single line.

```
div {
     overflow: hidden;
     text-overflow: ellipsis;
     white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Since you are looking for multi line ellipsis (which is not directly available in CSS), I think below link might help you : 
https://codepen.io/martinwolf/pen/qlFdp

There is also one Jquery plugin available which can be used : 
https://tpgblog.com/threedots/

Comment: With the help of yours, and the link's info I could solve it.
Thank you!